# How to create a .ipa file in XCode 4.6?

Tags: iphone, ipa, xcode4.6

I am trying to put my xcode project on my (jailbroken) iPhone. what can I do? i tried to Archive the product but it is greyed out. Also, when I plug in my iPhone and try to build it with xcode in my iPhone, it says "code signing error". can i do this without paying the 100 bucks for a developer account? I don't want to publish my apps in the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, running your app on a device requires a certificate, which requires a developer account AFAIK.